# Passing parameter to function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I want to call the following in my code somewhere.

```
scrollIntoViewElement(main-nav);
```

The following is the function:

```
// Element to scroll into view
scrollIntoViewElement(element) {
    document.getElementById('element').scrollIntoView();
}
```

The function should scroll the page into the view of the provided element id.

Is this correct? Or should it be...

```
// Element to scroll into view
scrollIntoViewElement(element) {
    document.getElementById("\'" + element + "\'").scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Not unless you have an element with the id "element". Just ditch the quotes and you'll be fine

Comment: `document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: Also `scrollIntoViewElement('main-nav');` if "main-nav" is the id of your element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `scrollIntoViewElement(main-nav);` means "Take the value of `main`, subtract the value of `nav`, and then call `scrollIntoViewElement` passing the result in as a parameter. If you want to pass in the string `main-nav`, you need quotes to tell the JavaScript parser you're using a literal string: `scrollIntoViewElement("main-nav");`

Within the function, you **don't** use quotes, because you want to use the value of the parameter, not the literal string `"element"`.

So:

```
scrollIntoViewElement("main-nav");
```

and

```
// Element to scroll into view
scrollIntoViewElement(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView();
}
```

This assumes you have an element with `id="main-nav"` in your document. It'll throw an exception if you don't, because `getElementById` will return `null`.